# I am getting error "array.sh: 3: array.sh: Syntax error: "(" unexpected"

Tags: arrays, bash, shell, ubuntu

I have written the following code:

```
#!/bin/bash
#Simple array
array=(1 2 3 4 5)

echo ${array[*]}
```

And I am getting error:
    array.sh: 3: array.sh: Syntax error: "(" unexpected

From what I came to know from Google, that this might be due to the fact that Ubuntu is now not taking "#!/bin/bash" by default... but then again I added the line but the error is still coming.

Also I have tried by executing `bash array.sh` but no luck! It prints blank.

My Ubuntu version is: Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: `sh array.sh` will generate that error because ordinary bourne shells, such as `dash`, do not understand arrays.  `bash array.sh` should work fine.  I tested your script and, under `bash`, it works for me.

Comment: @John1024, `bash array.sh` prints blank in my case.

Comment: What does `echo $BASH_VERSION` say?  You may have an old version of bash.

Comment: @NedDeily, 4.3.8(1)-release

Comment: In that case, your `bash` is new enough.  When I run the script, it prints `1 2 3 4 5`.  When I use `dash`, I get the error message that you quote.

Comment: @John1024, My other .sh files are also running fine with `bash` as well as `sh` command. But this array code is not working with any of them.

Comment: Is there a way to debug the code to find out where it is creating problem?

Comment: @Mistu4u What's the latest error you get?

Comment: Add `set -x` after the shebang line.

Comment: @NedDeily, I solved the problem miraculously. Please find my answer below.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Given that script:

```
#!/bin/bash
#Simple array
array=(1 2 3 4 5)

echo ${array[*]}
```

and assuming:

- It's in a file in your current directory named `array.sh`;
- You've done `chmod +x array.sh`;
- You have a sufficiently new version of bash installed in `/bin/bash` (you report that you have 4.3.8, which is certainly new enough); *and*
- You execute it correctly

then that should work without any problem.

If you execute the script by typing

```
./array.sh
```

the system will pay attention to the `#!/bin/bash` line and execute the script using `/bin/bash`.

If you execute it by typing something like:

```
sh ./array.sh
```

then it will execute it using `/bin/sh`. On Ubuntu, `/bin/sh` is typically a symbolic link to `/bin/dash`, a Bourne-like shell that *doesn't* support arrays. That will give you exactly the error message that you report.

The shell used to execute a script is not affected by which shell you're currently using or by which shell is configured as your login shell in `/etc/passwd` or equivalent (unless you use the `source` or `.` command).

In your own answer, you say you fixed the problem by using `chsh` to change your default login shell to `/bin/bash`. That by itself should not have any effect. (And `/bin/bash` is the default login shell on Ubuntu anyway; had you changed it to something else previously?)

What must have happened is that you changed the command you use from `sh ./array.sh` to `./array.sh` without realizing it.

Try running `sh ./array.sh` and see if you get the same error.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of using sh to run the script,

try the following command:

```
bash ./array.sh
```

Comment: The script already has `#!/bin/bash`. The whole point of a [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) is that you can just execute the command without specifying how. Just use `./array.sh`.

Answer (score -2):

I solved the problem miraculously. In order to solve the issue, I found a link where it was described to be gone by using the following code. After executing them, the issue got resolved.

```
chsh -s /bin/bash adhikarisubir

grep ^adhikarisubir /etc/passwd
```

FYI, "adhikarisubir" is my *username*.

After executing these commands, `bash array.sh` produced the desired result.

Comment: Strange. You should be able to run your bash scripts with the bash command even if your default shell is i.e. csh. I don't think this is a solution, only a 'work around'.

Comment: @BjørneMalmanger, Agreed! However I recorded this answer so that if someone else faces this strange behavior in the system, he may find this solution helpful.

Comment: I would be astonished if that made a difference. I strongly suspect you did something else that fixed the problem.